# Marketplace app + Provisioning API: check if user is admin

Tags: google-app-engine, provisioning, google-apps, google-apps-marketplace

I'm trying to check if a user is admin of their Google Apps domain, in an app installed from the Google Apps marketplace.

I added this to manifest.xml:

```
<Scope id="Provisioning API">
  <Url>https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/user/#readonly</Url>
  <Reason>This application can list domain users to give them permissions.</Reason>
</Scope>
```

Then I set a test handler to get it working:

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util

import gdata.alt.appengine
import gdata.apps.service
import gdata.auth

# App id, key and secret from the Google Apps Marketplace.
APPLICATION_ID = 'XXX'
CONSUMER_KEY = 'XXX'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'XXX'

class SetupHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, *args):
        # The domain where this app is installed.
        domain = 'my_customer_domain.com'
        # A username to check.
        username = 'webmaster'

        sig_method = gdata.auth.OAuthSignatureMethod.HMAC_SHA1
        service = gdata.apps.service.AppsService(source='tipfy-com',
                                                 domain=domain)
        service.SetOAuthInputParameters(sig_method, CONSUMER_KEY,
                                        consumer_secret=CONSUMER_SECRET,
                                        two_legged_oauth=True,
                                        requestor_id=APPLICATION_ID)
        service.ssl = True
        service.debug = True
        gdata.alt.appengine.run_on_appengine(service)

        lookup_user = service.RetrieveUser(username)
        if lookup_user.login.admin == 'true':
            res = username + ' is an admin.'
        else:
            res = username + ' is not an admin.'

        self.response.out.write(res)

app = webapp.WSGIApplication([
    ('/.*', SetupHandler),
], debug=True)

def main():
    util.run_wsgi_app(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But I get a 401 response ("Unknown authorization header"). I don't know what I'm doing incorrectly or how to debug it further.

- Is the manifest entry correct?
- Splitting `user.email()` is ok to get the user's username and domain? (I debugged it and in my case it was: I got 'webmaster' and 'example.com', which was the user and Google Apps domain where the app was installed).

What am I missing?

**Edit:** For some reason, the admin panel didn't ask permission to grant access to the provided scopes. After I granted it, the code above worked. So take it as a working example!

Comment: Just a thought, but you know that when you add a new <scope> to an existing marketplace app, the admin must go into the control panel to 'OK' the new request?

Comment: I'm testing it in my own domain (the app is not released yet). So I actually removed the app and re-added it with the new scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to re-add your app for the scopes work, just make sure in your GoogleApps admin dashboard, on the application settings, you "Grant access" and the **Data Access** is "**Granted**". Otherwise just grant that access.

Splitting `user.email()` works like a charm for me, because `user.nickname()` in localhost testing contains a full email, not like production (where it contains the username).

Make sure the user requesting is an **admin**.

Comment: I can't believe. Everything was working and the access was not granted! For some reason the manifest was updated but the "Grant" permission approval never appeared in the admin. Obrigado!

Comment: Just a note: `user.nickname()` doesn't work with SSO apps as the nickname will be the OpenId identifier -- nothing related to the Google Apps username. To get username, I used `user.email().split('@', 1)[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

I met exactly the same problem, which keep giving me:

## Unknown authorization header

### Error 401

I'm using the free version of Google Apps, is this might be the root cause of this problem? As i know Provisioning API only supports premium account.

Answer (score 0):

Admin apis [provisioning api etc.] are now available to editions of Google Apps.

http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/12/more-administrative-apis-now-available.html